# bundling css with webpack

Tags: webpack, aurelia, webpack-2

I am new to webpack. I am using it to bundle an aurelia app website.

It bundles the html, and it also finds all images and puts them into the dist folder.  This works and runs without error.

Now I want to bundle the css in the same way.  I am expecting for the css to get moved to the 'dist' folder like the images.

However, the css does not seem to get processed by webpack when I run build.  There are no messages about finding the css like there are with the images.

This is what I am expecting webpack to process:

```
<link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
const path = require("path");
const {AureliaPlugin} = require("aurelia-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: { main: "aurelia-bootstrapper" },

  ///dev
  devtool: 'source-map',

  ///Prod
  //devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "wwwroot", "dist"),
    filename: "app.js",
    publicPath: "/dist/",
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"],
    modules: ["App", "node_modules"],    
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.html$/i, loaders: "html-loader" },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },      {
          test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: "file-loader", options: {
              name: './images/[name].[hash].[ext]',
          }
        }
     ]
  },

  plugins: [
      new AureliaPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Comment: By default, Webpack will inline your CSS as Javascript tags that injects the CSS into the page. This sounds strange but it lets you do hot reloading in development. In production you extract them to a file using the ExtractTextPlugin, and require it with a normal link tag. No, this is not well designed software.

Comment: I would be happy to see it inline, but it's not happening. Maybe something in my config is off?

Comment: You're also supposed to require() the CSS files in your Javascript code, which is how webpack finds them.

Comment: Success, thank you.

Comment: (spam) maybe suggested reading http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the css will be embedded into your app.js. If you want to separate them, use css-loader in conjunction with ExtractTextPlugin:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: "css-loader"
            })
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
]
```

Note also to reference the added css in your html file:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/styles.css">
```

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin

Comment: I don't want to separate them to a different file.  The issue is that they are not getting embedded into app.js.  When the html is processed, the css-loader should be embedding it into app.js, but when I search, I don't see it in there. It should see the link and then from there, embed it correct?

Comment: if you import/require the css file within any js files processed by webpack, it should be embedded into app.js javascript eval function...